# Assertion Error in Python, Though both List i am comparing are same

Tags: python, list, assert

Please i need your help with the following code. I am trying to verify that the options in the Select Dropdown is as expected.

```
def getListOfExcess(self):
    expected_excess = ["Nil excess", "US$250 per annum", "US$500 per annum", "US$800 per claim",
                        "US$1,000 per annum", "US$1,600 per claim", "US$2,500 per annum", "US$5,000 per annum",
                        "US$10,000 per annum"]
    for excesses in expected_excess:
        print(excesses)
    # excess_dropdown_list = [element.text for element in
    #                         self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@name='pExcess']/div[2]/div/div/div/select")]
    #
    # print(*excess_dropdown_list)
 
    excess_list = self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@name='pExcess']/div[2]/div/div/div/select")
 
    excess = []
    for matched_element in excess_list:
        text = matched_element.text
        excess.append(text)
        if excess in excess_list and excess in excesses:
            print(matched_element, 'Excess type for Bronze are correct')
        else:
            print(matched_element, 'Excess type for Bronze are NOT correct')
        print(text)
        return text
```

the OutPut from my terminal is

```
Running method level setUp

Nil excess

US$250 per annum

US$500 per annum

US$800 per claim

US$1,000 per annum

US$1,600 per claim

US$2,500 per annum

US$5,000 per annum

US$10,000 per annum

<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="bc5d64e85c3d5318f0cd5c15dc083fdb", element="ec21f533-a4eb-4fb9-944c-12d9ba9f05b9")> Excess type for Bronze are NOT correct

Nil excess

US$250 per annum

US$500 per annum

US$800 per claim

US$1,000 per annum

US$1,600 per claim

US$2,500 per annum

US$5,000 per annum

US$10,000 per annum



PASSEDRunning method level tearDown

Running one time tearDown
```

Though the List looks same but i am unable to assert that the content are same.

What am i getting wrong please.

I will greatly appreciate your help

Comment: try replacing ```if excess in excess_list and excess in excesses:``` with ```if excess in excess_list and excess in expected_excess:```.

Comment: This line makes no sense `if excess in excess_list and excess in excesses`.  But you defined `excess = []` an empty list.  Nor is there a variable `excesses` anywhere in your code except as a loop variable further up...

Comment: If you just want to ensure that the same items are in list-A and list-B without concern for ordering (and you don't need to worry about duplicates, as your current code doesn't worry about them), you'd be better off converting them both to sets and just using `==` to compare the two sets. Then you could use set subtraction to find out _which items_ are in your actual set but not your expected one, or your expected set but not your actual one, so your error message can easily say _why_ the test is failing.

Comment: the way you're building your `excess` list and how you wrote your tests tell that they'll always fail.

Comment: i really don't think that picking the select element can yield the options in it without processing. `excess_list` is not a list.

Comment: okay, i just noticed the output. so `excess_list` is indeed not a list. you extracted the text from the options as just one string. it is only logical the assert fails. the best proof is that the if/else outputs only once

Comment: @Martin Thanks for you input, much appreciated. tried it but did not work.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your input i have now resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

```
def excess(self):
    exp_excess = ["Nil excess", "US$250 per annum", "US$500 per annum", "US$800 per claim", "US$1,000 per annum",
                  "US$1,600 per claim", "US$2,500 per annum", "US$5,000 per annum", "US$10,000 per annum",
                  "                "]

    excess_drp = (self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@name='pExcess']/div[2]/div/div/div/select")).text
    act_excess = excess_drp.split('\n')
    excessList = []
    excessList.append(act_excess)

    if(numpy.array_equal(numpy.array(exp_excess), numpy.array(act_excess))):
        assert True
        print("Both Excess List are equal")
    else:
        assert False
        print("Both Excess List are NOT equal")

    assert exp_excess == act_excess
```